# Coloring specific points in the point cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I need help in coloring specific points in a point cloud. I have the indices of the points which need to colored. Currently the point cloud is colored using the pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerGenericField for a specific field in the point type. 
And I have drawn a 3D box which contains the points that have to be colored differently. Currently the points which lie in the 3D box also have been colored using the pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerGenericField.

Cannot attach image because of reputation.

Comment: Please be more specific in what you are asking/ what is not working.  Also, please post the code that you have so far (including where u are adding, coloring, and displaying *spinning* the point cloud in the visualizer)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you,

First, you have to extract the indices of specific points in a pointcloud using `pcl::ExtractIndices` and store it in the new pointcloud variable,

and then, this example code might be used as a reference

```
inline float PackRGB(uint8_t r,uint8_t g,uint8_t b) {
  uint32_t color_uint = ((uint32_t)r << 16 | (uint32_t) g << 8 | (uint32_t)b);
  return *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&color_uint);
}

int main(){
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>()); //your cloud that you want to colorize

  cloud->width = (1000000);
  cloud->height = 1;
  cloud->points.resize(cloud->width * cloud->height);


  for(auto &it : cloud->points){
    it.x = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    it.y = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    it.z = 1024 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    it.rgb = PackRGB(63, 81, 181);
  }

  pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("cloudname.pcd", *cloud);

  return 0;
}
```